# Autocomplete textbox to use in a form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i'm trying to create an autocomplete box for a form.
Basically what I want to achieve is a textarea field that allows me to search the database for names belonging to a table and add them to a table through a form.
I managed to create this, but it allows me to search only one name at a time, while I would need to look for more names to add to the same textarea.

Basically I have a textarea and this must give me the possibility to insert more names:
name1
name2
...
Where each name is chosen from the drop-down menu that is created. In this way I could go to insert more "names" in the database.

**auto_complete.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Autocomplete TextBox</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <style>  
           ul{  
                background-color:#eee;  
                cursor:pointer;  
           }  
           li{  
                padding:12px;  
           }  
           </style>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <form method="post" action="insert_db.php">
                <h3 align="center">Box Text</h3><br />  
                <label>Enter  Name</label>  
                <br>&ensp;<textarea name="nominativo" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Name Surname" id="nominativo" class="form-control""  ></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Invia">
                <div id="nominativoList"></div>  
                </form>
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#nominativo').keyup(function(){  
           var query = $(this).val();  
           if(query != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"search.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{query:query},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          $('#nominativoList').fadeIn();  
                          $('#nominativoList').html(data);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){  
           $('#nominativo').val($(this).text());  
           $('#nominativoList').fadeOut();  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456789", "Personale");  


 if(isset($_POST["query"]))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Squadra WHERE Nominativo LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  
      $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '<li>'.$row["Nominativo"].'</li>';  
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '<li>Country Not Found</li>';  
      }  
      $output .= '</ul>';  
      echo $output;  
 }  

 ?>
```

**insert_db.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456789", "Personale");  
$nominativo = $_POST['nominativo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Prenotazione (Nominativo) VALUES ('$nominativo')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


?>
```

In your opinion how can i do?? 
Thank you for your attention and for your time.

Comment: you can use the `AND|OR` operators in your SELECT query.

Comment: use a prepared statement; you're open to an sql injection.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I can use AND | OR to select more than one field?

Comment: Yes you can. Note that `AND` requires an exact match of all columns. `OR` makes it so that it will find any  while skipping the ones that are not found.

Comment: you can also use a subquery where you can use bracketed queries. Something like `WHERE x=? AND y=? OR (a != ? AND b = ?)`. But that may be too advanced for you right now, but I think you get the gist of it.

Comment: Yes i think that it is too advanced for me. I don’t have  understand how can i use AND in my select query. Thanks for your help

Comment: Then use `WHERE col_x = ? AND col_y = ? AND col_z = ?` or `WHERE col_x =? OR col_y = ? OR col_z = ?`. The `?` are example placeholders. You will need to fill those as you need.

Comment: Col_x is for example "Nominativo"? 
And also what means that ? are placeholders?
What I would like to do is take the data directly from the database, so I can do it?

Comment: when we speak of placeholders, it can mean one of two things. 1) It's representative of something that is unknown and to be replaced by actual values. Where `col_x=?` can be replaced by `col_x = '$var_x'`. 2) The `?` is also a placeholder syntax character when using a prepared statement. For your code, you'd use the mysqli_ method http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php